# AppVeyor + Coverity on Windows with C++

Tags: c++, windows, appveyor, coverity

The Coverity Scan Analysis Tool seems to think my C++ project is C#

```
cov-build.exe : Emitted 1 C# compilation units (100%) successfully At line:8 char:1
+ & "cov-build.exe" `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Emitted 1 C# co...%) successfully:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError   [WARNING] Emitted 0 C/C++ compilation units (0%) successfully [WARNING] Recoverable errors were encountered during 4 of these C/C++ compilation units. 1 C# compilation units (100%) are ready for analysis 0 C/C++ compilation units (0%) are ready for analysis  For more details, please look at: 
    C:/projects/peernet/cov-int/build-log.txt Command executed with exception: [WARNING] Emitted 0 C/C++ compilation units (0%) successfully [WARNING] Recoverable errors were encountered during 4 of these C/C++ compilation units. 1 C# compilation units (100%) are ready for analysis 0 C/C++ compilation units (0%) are ready for analysis  For more details, please look at: 
    C:/projects/peernet/cov-int/build-log.txt
```

Not sure what's going on here but I can't get it to properly build with AppVeyor and upload any results to Coverity.
Here's the appveyor.yml script: https://github.com/kklouzal/PeerNet/blob/next/appveyor.yml

Does anyone know how I can get this to work properly?

Comment: You need to run `cov-configure` and tell it which language you are using.

Comment: The issue may also be with the instructions to the compiler.  Coverity gets its input from the compiler. If the compiler is running a C# program, then Coverity gets C# data.

Comment: The compiler is running a c++ application, it's 100% C/C++ code. Can you point me to any appveyor.yml examples using cov-configure?

Comment: Very unlikely that you have 100% C/C++ code since they are two different languages.  Coverity has different checkers for C++ than C language.  First step:  Figure out which language you are programming in.

Comment: It's definitely not c# like the output says.